# Identify duplicate rows based on specifc columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a query to identify duplicate rows by adding an IsDuplicate column with the text yes/no. The query needs to check for duplicates only within certain columns.

What I have so far is almost correct, except that I need the yes to appear all of the duplicate rows. This is just a simplified example and there will be other columns that need to be selected, but not included in the duplicate checks.

```
select Emp_Name
  ,Company
  ,Join_Date
  ,Resigned_Date,
    case 
        when ROW_NUMBER () over     
        (partition by 
                Emp_Name, Company, Join_Date
                     ,Resigned_Date
                order by Emp_Name, Company, Join_Date
                     ,Resigned_Date) > 1 then 'Yes'
        else 'No'
        end  as IsDuplicate 
  ,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Emp_Name, Company, Join_Date
                     ,Resigned_Date
                      order by Emp_Name, Company, Join_Date
                     ,Resigned_Date) RowNumber ,
                     Hours from Emp_Details
```

https://sqliteonline.com/#fiddle=dbdab61529544220bd3319407dbafd4beba1671d14ef00bf1635011c6f233dea

[image: Example query]

Comment: Are you using SQL Server (tagged) or SQLite (as used in your link)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I have so far is almost correct, except that I need the yes to appear all of the duplicate rows.

You want `count(*)` rather than `row_number()`:

```
(case when count(*) over (partition by Emp_Name, Company, Join_Date, Resigned_Date) > 1
      then 'Yes' else 'No'
 end)  as IsDuplicate
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if problem not resolved

```
select E1.Emp_Name
      ,E1.Company
      ,E1.Join_Date
      ,E1.Resigned_Date, CASE WHEN E2.Count IS NOT NULL THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END Duplicate
FROM Emp_Details E1
LEFT OUTER JOIn(
select EMP_NAME, company, JOIN_DATE, resigned_date, count(1)count
FROM EMP_DETAILS
GROUP BY EMP_NAME, company, JOIN_DATE, resigned_date HAVING COUNT()>1) E2 ON E1.Emp_Name=E2.emp_name and E1.join_date=E2.join_date AND E1.resigned_date=E2.resigned_date
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're asking since your query appears to give the results you describe.

However if I were to ignore your example query and just write a query based on your given specification I would suggest something like the following

```
with d as (
  select * ,
    row_number() over(partition by emp_name, company, join_date, resigned_date order by join_date) as rn
from Emp_Details E1
)
select emp_name, company, join_date, resigned_date, 
  case when rn=1 then 'No' else 'Yes' end IsDuplicate
from d
```

Edit...

```
select emp_name, company, join_date, resigned_date, 
  case when count(*) over(partition by Emp_Name, Company, Join_Date, Resigned_Date) = 1 then 'No' else 'Yes' end IsDuplicate
from Emp_Details
order by emp_name, company, join_date
```

Comment: Sorry, my question was maybe not well worded.  My example query in the image needs to be yes, yes for the first 2 rows.

Comment: @KevinRobinson Sorry I misunderstood - normally when I deal with duplicates I assume an original row and then subsequent duplicates; I see you've already got a solution - I've edited my answer anyway for completeness as it's the default solution you would use to indicate all rows with a duplicate.